# Open link in same browser tab

Tags: windows, delphi, url, browser

How do I open a link in the same browser tab? I tried this code:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'http://site.com', '_self', nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

But it continues to open the link in a new table.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to understand do you mean a new tab in your own web browser application using a `TWebBrowser` or do you mean a new tab in whatever default web browser is there? I'm assuming the second... Also, what do you mean by a "new table"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[I've written on this topic before](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.nativeapi/200809/080905119.html):

> `ShellExecute` has absolutely no notion of "tab." In fact, it doesn't
>   even have a notion of "default browser." All it does is find whatever
>   program is configured for file names that start with "http://" and
>   execute the configured command line.
>
> What the browser does with the new command line is its own choice.
>   The API function has no control. Sometimes, the browser allows the
>   user to configure it.
>
> Opening a new tab or window is the safest thing to do. Neither you
>   nor the browser knows whether the user is still using the previous
>   tab or window.

Comment: So there is nothing to do from the code? Oh well, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A possible entry point is using OLE Automation. Using this technique you can connect with any existing instance of MSIE, so that you can bring the current browsing window to a new url.